# Ionic 4 form input is stuck when typing using keyboard in iOS device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm really struggling to figure out the root cause why my 'form input' are `stuck` when I'm typing using the hardware keyboard in iOS device. 
What I have done so far:

> - Reinstalling the Cordova keyboard plugin, using the latest
> - Reinstalling the WKWebView, using the latest
> - Recreate new project, copy old code to the newest project and try to run it on a device, unfortunately, the error keeps showing up

So what I figured out is the problem is not from the src files, because the old days I tried to run in the iOS device it was successfully

This link video showing up how the error come:

```
https://streamable.com/sgi8u
```

Xcode Log:

```
2020-01-28 18:23:59.208024+0800 apps[18863:356008] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fb74342a070; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000020b48a0>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2020-01-28 18:23:59.208179+0800 apps[18863:356008] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fb74342a070; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000020b48a0>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2020-01-28 18:23:59.691556+0800 apps[18863:356008] CDVIonicKeyboard: updating frame
```

Config XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.info.apps" version="3.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Ionic Apps</name>
    <description>Ionic App</description>
    <author email="ionic@ionic.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Apps</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>This apps wants to access your camera</string>
        </edit-config>
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="216" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-108@2x.png" width="216" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker" spec="^2.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crop" spec="^0.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.1.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.1.2">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^3.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.9.2">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.1.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="8.1.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="8.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.9.0) : 0.8.0
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.9

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v12.11.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.11.3
   OS      : macOS Catalina
   Xcode   : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/keyboard

Comment: Check this link for keyboard resize for ios, here your problem will be solved by needing the prefences of keyboard resize.

Comment: @MostafaHarb It's doesn't work, the form input is still stuck

Comment: Did you rebuild your project after adding it?

Comment: Cordova 9 is not stable yet. It has come issues. Try downgrading to 8.1.2. Use npm install cordova@8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external keyboard connected? I wrestled with this for awhile before I realized that the keyboard wasn't appearing on *any* app. I had a BT presentation remote connected to my device and it basically functions as a keyboard with a limited number of keys.